# The system cannot find the file specified Error on text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file name.txt that contains the ff: code

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%s in (C:\user\files\title.txt) do (
log normal "c:\user\user-log.txt"
)
```

Now I have a batch file that calls names.txt. However, it always shows

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How to solve this issue?Is it possible to have a batch code on a text file?

Comment: You can have batch code in txt but dont expect to execute it as you are running the batch file. By the way how you are executing it when you have above error ? Also what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Shaikh Mohammed Shariq

Im am using a batch file that calls specific variable where the location of name.txt was stored (set varBCscript=@C:\user\userfiles\name.txt)

Comment: Can you please post the code of your batch file which calls above variable ? Also can you double check that the file path is correct and the file is available at the same location described above ?

Comment: @Shaikh Mohammed Shariq

BTW, do we have any option where in we can pass the content of a file into another text file? for example I have name.txt where one value must get from another text file. I only need to get the first line from another text file.

Comment: Yes you can read the text file data and also pass it in another file through batch file itself. Can you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve so that we can work in that direction ?

Comment: For example the content of my name.txt file is to display the content of file1.txt. How can we achieve this in txt file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66780/discussion-between-shaikh-mohammed-shariq-and-peters).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed you want to read a file and append read content into another file. For that you can use below script created based on answers from these posts

[Reading a text file line by line and storing it in an array using batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866089/reading-a-text-file-line-by-line-and-storing-it-in-an-array-using-batch-script)

[Append text with .bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139157/append-text-with-bat)

```
@echo off
set "file=F:\FileToReadFrom.txt"
set /A i=0

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%file%") do (
set /A i+=1

call set array[%%i%%]=%%a
call set n=%%i%%
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do call echo %%array[%%i]%%>> F:\AppendToFile.txt
```

Above code you need to put in batch file also you need to replace your path for **FileToReadFrom.txt** and **AppendToFile.txt** as per your requirement.

Let me know if this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: OP is hard to understand, but from what I understood, `type file1.txt>>name.txt` should do.

Comment: Yes this is what is required as per my chat with @PeterS. Neat solution.