# Concatenate string and txt file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, concatenation

How do you concatenate a string to a text file in batch file?
Example:
I have a text file - cdrom.txt with this output:

```
Caption                  SerialNumber      Size          
SMI USB DISK USB Device  AA00000000000485  15825438720   
Hitachi HTS547550A9E384  2J1100159GVPAZ    500105249280
```

I need to put a label at the topmost of the line so that it would look like this:

```
CDROM
Caption                  SerialNumber      Size          
SMI USB DISK USB Device  AA00000000000485  15825438720   
Hitachi HTS547550A9E384  2J1100159GVPAZ    500105249280
```

Comment: i tried type CDROM cdrom.txt >> cdrom.txt but it has a wrong syntax

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append text with .bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139157/append-text-with-bat)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ren cdrom.txt cdrom.tmp
echo CDROM > cdrom.txt
type cdrom.tmp >> cdrom.txt
del cdrom.tmp
```

Comment: it says it cannot find the file specified @monacraft

Answer (score 0):

Chevron **>** characters provide redirection in windows command processor. So, to write a string to somefile.txt, we write:

```
echo myString > somefile.txt
```

executing this command writes a *new* file each time, due to the single > (write redirection).

Using a double chevron **>>** *appends* the prefix text to the file instead. So the command:

```
echo myString2 >> somefile.txt
```

would append myString2 to the somefile.txt file, usually on a new line, since the command processor prefixes a newline (Windows style CRLF) to the prefix of the >> operator before writing it out to the file.

Building on this, your specific case would lead to :

```
echo CDROM > cdrom1.txt
type cdrom.txt >> cdrom1.txt
del cdrom.txt
ren cdrom1.txt cdrom.txt
```

If you'd like more fine-grained stream redirection, you'll need to read up more :P

[Look here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)